when i use direction vertical in swiper slider swiper-slider get infinite height
When I use direction vertical in Swiper.js slider swiper-slider get infinite height.
function imgWithTextSlider() {
   var swiper = new Swiper(".imgWithTextSlider", {      
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 15,
      direction: 'vertical',       
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      freeMode: true       
    });
}


Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question. Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add all the relevant code.

Your code provides basic template of Swiper, and says not too much. Height issues usually depends on CSS. Could you show html and css, either?
